# Multiple SQL commands with one connection

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to execute multiple commands, but with one connection. Below is an example

```
MySqlCommand myCommand = myConnection.CreateCommand();
MySqlCommand myCommand2;

myCommand.CommandText = "Some query text"

MySqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader.Read())
{

    myCommand2 = myConnection2.CreateCommand();

    myCommand2.CommandText = "Query with parameters from myCommand"

    MySqlDataReader myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

    while (myReader2.Read())
    {

    }

}
```

I wish to do this code with only one myConnection, is this possible? Because if I delete myConnection2 and replace them with myConnection I receive an error as the first command is still open.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "POOLING=FALSE;" at the end of your MySQL ConnectionString.

Comment: doesn't work i receive error "Devart.Data.MySql.MySqlException: Commands out of sync; You can't run this command now"

Comment: Ok,try to reuse the command,change the `CommandText` property and execute the reader again in the same MySqlCommand.

Answer (score 0):

open a single connection and build a little

```
public static object QueryHelper(string command)
{
    ...
}
```

that use a

```
public static bool ReadyToQuery;
```

to wait until first command ended to run the second.

simply because **every connection** can do only **one reader at time**.

Comment: not solution for this problem. i need execute sedcond query during first query. From first query i receive parameters, that i need to use with second query if is it clear.

Comment: as i said before, every

**Connection** can execute N **ExecuteNonQuery** commands (like insert , update, delete) but **only one ExecuteReader** at time

you have to do SQL side using subquery 
[MySql manual](http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/subqueries_part_1.html)

or doing the first query, passing parameters to the second using c# variables, or using 2 connections... is your choice.

obviously, for performance reasons, the best thing is to do it MySql side using a single query.